# How to I get this parsed data back to the user with either PrintWriter or JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, countdown

I want to build a countdown in which the user enters a date and time into a form and the server sends him back the time remaining until that date, and dynamically updates it second by second.

I managed to create this countdown to print in the console by using a Thread with a sleep time of 1000, but I don't know how send the data back to the user in a dynamic way. I tried with PrintWriter but for some reason it does not work. Do I need to use response.setAttribute in a loop for each passing second and call the requestDispatcher or something? Anyways here is the code.

the form - (should the method be post or get n this case, and why?)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome to the Mega Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Please Enter your Event</h1>
<br>
<form method="GET" action ="CounterServlet">
    <h2>Please Enter The Event name</h2><br>
    <input type = "text" name = "eventName">
    <h2>Please Enter the date</h2><br>
    <input type = "date" name = "eventData">
    <input type = "time" name = "eventTime">
    <br>
    <input type = "Submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the servlet

```
public class CounterServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGET(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        String eventName = request.getParameter("eventName");
        String eventDate = request.getParameter("eventDate");
        String eventTime = request.getParameter("eventTime");

        String dateAndTime = eventDate + eventTime.substring(0, 5);
        CounterService service = new CounterService();
        LocalDateTime theParsedUserInput = service.parseDate(dateAndTime);
        service.setDateTime(theParsedUserInput);
        Runnable r = new Counter(service);
        Thread a = new Thread(r);
        a.start();

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>"+a+"</body></html>");
    }
}
```

the business logic(the main method is used only for testing in the console)

```
public class CounterService {
    LocalDateTime dateTime;

    public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public LocalDateTime parseDate(String eventDate) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(eventDate, formatter);
        return dateTime;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CounterService cs = new CounterService();
        LocalDateTime a = LocalDateTime.of(2021, 11, 11, 21, 43, 44);
        cs.setDateTime(a);


        Runnable r = new Counter(cs);
        new Thread(r).start();

    }

}
```

And the runnable

```
package com.example.service;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Counter implements Runnable {
    CounterService counter;

    public Counter(CounterService cs) {
        this.counter = cs;
    }

    public void setCounter(CounterService cs) {
        this.counter = cs;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            boolean x = true;
            while (x) {
                LocalDateTime countFromThisDate = counter.getDateTime();
                LocalDateTime substracting = countFromThisDate.minusSeconds(1);
                counter.setDateTime(substracting);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(counter.getDateTime());
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That is a job for JavaScript, which executes in the browser. Not for Java, which executes on the server.

Comment: is there no way i can do this with java only?I tried searching on the web and found countdown inmplementation but it was dirrectly in the JSP skiping the business layer/ServletLayer as it is in my case.

Comment: Realistically, no. The only way would be to generate a meta refresh (if that still exists) that would tell the browser to refresh the whole page every second. You really don't want to do that.

Comment: ok, so could you help me implement this with js then?

Comment: That's not what Stackoverflow is for. Read some documentation, practice, use Google, try something, and if after doing all of this, you have a concrete question about the code you tried, then ask another question.

Comment: thing is i don't know where to start.I know a bit of js with its dom manipulation, but you just send me in a complete new direction without any other hints. I saw a guy on youtube create a Countdown in a JSP file wich is just another Servlet.Thing is he is using scriptlets i want to do it by coding it in several distinct layers.I don't think its not possible, just look at this 3 minute video and tell me otherwise. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYTqPlVRrwE

Comment: You could start by googling for "how to implement a countdown in JavaScript". It's really that simple to get started since search engines exist.

Comment: The guy in the video uses scriptlets (ouch!) and tells the browser to refresh the whole page after one second.

Comment: i don't think you understand, i want to do it in java + jsp not in javascript.Sending people to the search engine is not helpful, sometimes you don't find what you need even after hours of searching.

Comment: Yes. Some people also want to cross the ocean using a car. That's just the wrong tool for the job. HTTP is a request-response protocol. Once the server has sent the response, that's it. The server can't do anything more to change the content of the page. You have to deal with the reality, and accept it. The ocean is made of water, and cars don't drive on water. So a boat  is the right tool for the job.